# Header files and namespaces in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with header files and namespaces. If we define functions in the namespaces then we can use the name of that namespace as identifier.

This is ok but what is really confusing that most of the functions in C++(which are declared in **different** header files)  are in the **std** namespace.

Now is the namespace inside the header file or header file inside the namespace?

If the namespace is inside each header file then how can you make a function(which is declared and fully implemented in header file) member of that predefined namespace?

A concrete example:

When i try to use `string` in C++ then i use `#include <string>` but then i have to use the identifier to call a function(like `std ::stoi`).

Now when i open the header file `string` i see that `stoi` is fully implemented in the header file `string`. So how is this function a member of `std` namespace because in `string` header file i don't see `std` anywhere nor it is made a member of `std` namespace explicitly.

My Question can be very basic but i don't find answer anywhere. Simply declaring a function in namespace and then using it is simple but a function which is declared and implemented in header file, how is that function a member of any namespace and how can one namespace have functions from different header files?

It would be enough if someone tells me how `stoi` is made a member of `std`. The rest i can do by myself.

Comment: Each header file declares the same namespace e.g. `namespace std`. The contents are merged together. It's purely a mechanism for reducing clutter (qualified name lookup).

Comment: There must be std:: in <string> but those files are implementation defined. Header files and namespaces are unrelated. Include just pastes the code.

Comment: I want someone to tell me how `stoi` is made a member of `std`. I can understand macros and if i open that file(string) , i can't see where it happpend.

Comment: Namespaces can span multiple files. Odds are you can't find the `namespace std` because it's in a file included by `<string>`. For example in g++'s library implementation `<string>` includes `<bits/basic_string.h>` which declares `namespace std` and `stoi` inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: If it helps, remember that when you `#include` a file, the result is that that file is _literally_ copied-and-pasted into the source code. So there's no real difference between using multiple files with versus a single file, when you have the same namespace appearing multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual studio the `<string>` header has this line:

```
_STD_BEGIN
```

it is a macro defined as:

```
#define _STD_BEGIN  namespace std {
```

So the namespace is specified in the header file. Then way down on line 179 or so we find `stoi`:

```
inline int stoi(const string& _Str, size_t *_Idx = nullptr,
```

and further down still:

```
_STD_END
```

which expands to:

```
}
```

at the end of the `std` namespace.

Comment: Note: Identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (like `_STD_BEGIN` and `_STD_END`) are reserved. Don't use them in your own code, unless you're writing a compiler or standard library implementation and you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Namespaces can be added to. For example, in one file you might have:

```
  namespace myspace {
      int f();
  }
```

and in another:

```
  namespace myspace {
      void g();
  }
```

now both `f` anf `g` are functions in the namespace `myspace`.  You could also provide the definitions of the functions in the above code, if you wished. Or in an implementation file you could do:

```
  namespace myspace {
      int f() {
           return 42;
      }
  }
```